# How to wait before screenshot of webpage using selenium and phantomjs in python3?

Tags: python, ajax, python-3.x, selenium, phantomjs

Would like to create an image of a webpage but must wait to allow it to fully load (inc. AJAX).

The wait time should be set by an hardcoded value rather than waiting on an element.

The following takes a screenshot with no wait:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(w,h)
driver.get('webpage_address')
driver.save_screenshot('/path/to/dir/foo.png')
driver.quit()
```

Based on some [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(w,h)
driver.implicitly_wait(t)
driver.get('webpage_address')
driver.save_screenshot('/path/to/dir/foo.png')
driver.quit()
```

However, this does not output an image nor does it seem to be waiting.

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: Are you sure the page is loading properly? PhantomJS is a chromeless browser that uses QtWebKit  for page rendering, not the latest and greatest Gecko or Chromium engine. I'd be interested to know if there are any JavaScript errors being thrown. You might be trying to solve the wrong problem...

Comment: Hi @GregBurghardt, The initial example without a wait timer does seem to be working intermittently after more repeated use. Is there a way to go about debugging? Can't seem to find a verbose mode.

Comment: What if you call `time.sleep(10)` to brute force pause the thread before taking the screen shot? Maybe up that sleep time to 30 seconds just to see?

Comment: Hi @GregBurghardt, Switched out `implicitly_wait` for `time.sleep(30)`. This appears to be working better and the same screenshot is produced each time the script is run. However, the AJAX changes to the webpage are not in the screenshot. It's almost as if they are not currently being observed by `driver`. Tried up to 60secs sleep with no change to the output. Any ideas..? **Many thanks!**

Comment: Is there JavaScript on the page listening for an event generated by the user that isn't occurring during the PhantomJS browser session? Is a user action required for the AJAX calls to be triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
or
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
```

Here we are implicitly asking the code to waiting for 10 seconds

Comment: This seems to return a blank image; the same as using `driver.implicitly_wait(t)`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps waiting until an element is present on the given page, which would mean it's fully loaded (not in all cases) you can then proceed to take a screenshot :)

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myElement"))

driver.save_screenshot('/path/to/dir/foo.png')
```

Comment: I've tried this method also. The webpage is generated almost totally asynchronously so the approach is possibly not well suited? There is no element that is guaranteed to load last and therefore be tracked. If the 'container div' is used the code runs immediately as it appears loaded. However, am I missing something further here? **Many thanks!**

Comment: From your experience, what would you say is the total wait-time until the page is fully loaded, in a non-automated fashion?

Comment: worst-case, it would be ~30secs. `time.sleep(60)` didn't resolve the issue fully.

Comment: Interesting, one of the comments above you said that even though you had increased the wait time to the above range, you were still not grabbing the Ajax content. Perhaps grabbing a screenshot with another library that's not selenium, could yield some better results. A few options being: https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/examples.html

Comment: This is correct, the AJAX is still causing problems. Does `python mss` work in a headless environment?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't, as it would act independently from headless :)

Comment: If you feel like this post helped in anyway, don't forget to mark it when you get a moment :)